# How to select cell next to macro linked hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a hyperlink with a code linked to it in cell A1.

Cells B1->E1 have data in them

I want once the hyperlink is clicked, to cut cells B1->E1

I want to paste these in a different tab but I am familiar with that part of the code.

This is a big sheet so I don't want to cut cells B1->E1 specifically. I want to cut the cells next to the hyperlink whichever row is clicked.

What I am trying to do;

```
A                   B            C              D           E  
hyperlink          value        value          value      value      
hyperlink          value        value          value      value      
hyperlink          value        value          value      value      
hyperlink          value        value          value      value
```

Code I tried

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) 
    Dim r As Range 
    Set r = Range(Target.SubAddress) 
    Range("B7:E7").Select 
    Selection.Cut 
    Sheets("Wash Bay").Select 
    Worksheets("Wash Bay").Range("B6").Activate 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please understand this is not a code writing service.  Please post the code you have tried and if you ran into any specific errors.  I suggest reading the following [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi sorry about that , I do have a code kinda but I didn't know I was supposed to post, thanks for letting me know. here is what I got ;                                                                                                              Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range(Target.SubAddress)

    Range("B7:E7").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Wash Bay").Select
    Worksheets("Wash Bay").Range("B6").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
End Sub

Comment: Perfect! that worked. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (almost) getting a reference to the range you want (in `r`), then not using it.

And, you don't need any of that `Select` / `Activate` stuff anyway (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for useful tips)

Your code could be simply (assuming sheet "Wash Bay" is in the same workbook as the code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range(Target.SubAddress).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 4)
    r.Cut ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Wash Bay").Range("B6")
End Sub
```

Comment: cool thanks , that makes the code a little neater. if I have a follow up question on the pasting part of this do I need to start a new thread or can I just post the question here with you?

Comment: Generally ask a new Q if it can be asked as a good stand alone Q- you'll get more eyes on it.  If it's a minor point, I don't mind addressing it here

Comment: I actually got it figured out, thanks anyways though I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 4).Cut Sheets("Wash Bay").Range("B6")
```

Note you can use the `Destination` parameter for `Cut` to specifiy where to paste the cut cells.  No need to select/activate.